# XPath in PHPUnit testing with Zend

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework, phpunit, zend-test

I have this apparently basic code:

```
$docSrc = 
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head><title /></head>
    <body><p>Test paragraph.</p></body>
    </html>';
$domDoc = new DOMDocument();
$domDoc->loadXML($docSrc);
$xpath  = new DOMXPath($domDoc);
$nodeList = $xpath->query('//p');
$this->assertTrue($nodeList->length == 1);
```

It should succeed, but fails miserably, the length is 0. I have been looking for a solution all day, but to no avail.

---

Wow thanks! It works! Unfortunately, my original code:

```
$query = new Zend_Dom_Query($docSrc);
$xpathQuery = '//p';
$result = $query->queryXpath($xpathQuery);
$this->assertTrue($result->count() == 1);
```

thinks it is an XML and perform loadXML. Do you have any idea why this happens?

---

Ok I found the culprit somewhere in the Zend Library:

```
if ('<' . '?xml' == substr(trim($document), 0, 5)) {
    return $this->setDocumentXml($document, $encoding);
}
```

I wonder if this is correct since it IS an XML document, but load XML does not work.

---

Ok I’m doing some research. Apparently, the problem has something to do with namespaces...

Comment: Unrelated suggestion: using the more specific assertions such as `assertEquals()` will produce more informative failure messages. The above becomes `self::assertEquals(1, $result->count());` so a failure will say, "Expected 1 but was 3" rather than "Expected true but was false."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change line 2 to:

```
$domDoc->loadHTML($docSrc);
```

Answer (score 0):

There IS a bug, workaround is:

```
    $docSrc = 
        '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head><title /></head>
        <body><p>Test paragraph.</p></body>
        </html>';
    $domDoc = new DOMDocument();
    $domDoc->loadXML($docSrc);
    $xpath  = new DOMXPath($domDoc);
    $xpath->registerNamespace('xhtml', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml');
    $nodeList = $xpath->query('//xhtml:p');
    $this->assertTrue($nodeList->length == 1);
```